# How to procedurally add a precious metal vein to rock

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, procedural

First of all, here is an example picture of how the effect looks (source: http://marksteinmetz.photoshelter.com/image/I0000OqcTcB07acQ):

[image]

This is different from the usual rust texture in that the gold (or other precious metal vein) is somewhat continuous and not just randomly distributed over the (volume of the) rock.

It would be nice to be able to somehow procedurally generate this texture with a percentage of gold content (e.g., 0%-100%) and take two inputs:

1. One for the gold texture
2. One for the rock texture

..., mixing the two procedurally based on a percentage ratio as previous explained.

Even a surface texture version of this would be greatly appreciated. I tried searching, but can't find anything that produces an effect similar to what is show in the picture (displacement aside, but would be a great bonus).

Comment: Did you tried something so far or do you want someone make it for you?

Comment: Sometimes, you try but come up with such ugly attempts that you are too embarrassed to share them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a texture to determine the mix between two shaders

[image]

Adding a color ramp (or RGB curves would work as well) you can control how the texture affects the mix.

[image]

Comment: While I haven't personally done it, I have seen tutorials that use vertex painting as input to the node system - so I am reasonably confident that if you want more specific control over where the gold goes, you could paint onto your mesh and then pass that through in much the same way.

Comment: Can this impact volume as well for a 3d penetrating look of the veins through either SSS or transparent materials?

Comment: you can make this work with any shader, the idea is to show you that you can use textures to determine how to mix shaders. You can make the shader as complicated as you want.